# Powershell: "Return" is not exiting a function

Tags: powershell

I have a function that does not appear to exit when it encounters the keyword `return`. Instead it continues with the function. Here is the relevant snippet of the function:

```
function Do-Something($photoNum,$photoLabelArrUniq) {
...
    $fileLabelArrUniq=(Get-ChildItem -filter "$photoNum *.tif").name.substring(4,14) | sort-object | get-unique

    $photoSideArr=@()
    $photoSideArr=($fileLabelArrUniq.substring(0,1))

    write-host "photoSideArr: $photoSideArr"

    $a=3
    $photoSideArr | Foreach-Object {
        if ($_ -eq "B") {
            write-host "return: $fileLabelArrUniq"
            write-host "Hello There"
            $a=4
            return $fileLabelArrUniq
        }
    }
write-host "a: $a"
...
return $something
}
```

and the results are:

```
photoSideArr: B F F
return: B OR 06K24b 07 F CC 06K24b 07 F OR 06K24b 07 #This is an array with 3 members: "B OR 06K24b 07","F CC 06K24b 07","F OR 06K24b 07"
Hello There
a: 4
```

The `return: B OR 06K24b 07 F CC 06K24b 07 F OR 06K24b 07` and `Hello There` indicate it is in the condition `if` block and therefore should return `$fileLabelArrUniq` and then exit the function. However, as evidenced by the result `a: 4` (which can only occur if in the `if` block than includes the `return` keyword), the function continues after it was supposed to return a result to the main script and exit.

Is my understanding of how `return` functions in scripts wrong or am I missing something with the syntax? I am at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ForEach-Object` takes a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.3), which is kind of like a function. `Return` only exits the current call of the script block, not the outer function, so the `ForEach-Object` is still going and will call the script block again with the next item.

The easiest way to let your loop exit the function is to use a `ForEach` loop, which does not interpret the braced block syntax as a script block:

```
ForEach ($_ In $photoSideArr) {
    # Do something with $_
    # "Return" in here will exit the enclosing function
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, this solved my problem and a few problems I didn't think were associated with this. This will help me to write better scripts in the future.